# Filled areas in gnuplot that disappear when the curve exits the graph area

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I was about to ask this question here but a minute before doing it I figured how to solve the problem. Since I think other people might have experienced the same issue, I answer my own question.

Imagine that you want to draw a curve and a shade below it, for instance y = x². In gnuplot, something of the sort is realized like this

```
plot -x**2 with filledcurves x1
```

which yields the following graph:

[image: -x²]

Now imagine that for some reason you want to restrict the range of the y axis so the max. value is -10. Then

```
set yrange [*:-10]
plot -x**2 with filledcurves x1
```

yields the following:

[image: -x² with restricted y range]

which looks terrible. Even though you're asking gnuplot to shade the area between the curve and the x axis, the fact that the part of the curve outside the graph is not being rendered is preventing this from happening properly.

How do you fix it? Answer below.

Comment: This is a bug in the clipping code, which is fixed in the development version. Unfortunately, this won't make it in an upcoming patchlevel of the 4.6 branch, but will rather be available only in the next stable major release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the issue, you need a conditional plot that turns the curve into y = -10 when the original function is outside the graph region:

```
set yrange [*:-10]
plot -x**2 <= -10 ? -x**2 : -10 with filledcurves x1
```

which gives the desired result:

[image: -x² nicely plotted]

Note that without further styling the shaded areas cover the axis tics and the title text, but that's another matter.

I hope this helps some people.